# What are the additional fields in wp_comments used for?

Tags: comments, database, comment-meta

I'm working on a rather odd implementation that stretches the limits of WP a little - its a healthcare site where patients are a custom post type and procedure requests related to each patient are stored in comments on that post. I started off by storing alot of data in commentmeta, but I want an easier way to access it than having to pull from a meta table. I'd also like to be able to use the built-in functions where available (**wp_insert_comment** can set most of the fields in wp_comments table through the arguments passed to it).

My question is - where are these other values set and accessed in WordPress? Specifically, I'm curious about:

- comment_karma
- comment_type
- comment_approved

I have one meta value I want to set, which I'm hoping to use `comment_type` for. I also want to set a flag on each request to show whether or not it has been confirmed and responded to. It seems like `comment_karma` would work well for this, as it is completely unsused, although I'm not sure if it can be set directly with **wp_insert_comment**.

Are there any consequences I should be aware of when doing this? Would I be better off just adding additional columns to the table, or does this approach sound like it would work?

Comment: There was a short movement to remove it for version 3.1 ... but since some systems still hook onto it, it's staying there for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## comment_karma

This field is used by a few plug-ins to help you manage your comments.  There are a [few good articles](http://trueslant.com/rogertheriault/2010/02/26/curating-and-filtering-blog-post-comments-with-wordpress-and-ajax/) explaining its exact use floating around on the Internet.  But you should note that this field is actually just not used.  As Mark Jaquith said once, it's a "there if you want to use it this."

There was a short movement to remove it for version 3.1 ... but since some systems still hook onto it, it's staying there for now.

## comment_type

Is this a comment, a trackback, or a pingback?  This helps theme devs separate out the different types of "comments" in the front-end display.

## comment_approved

Is the comment pending moderation, spam, or approved by the author?  Just helps you manage what is and isn't OK for display on the site.

Answer (score 2):

- `comment_karma` - no idea, doesn't seem meaningful in current code;
- `comment_type` - this marks pingbacks/trackbacks, empty for normal comments;
- `comment_approved` - approval (`0` or `1`) and spam (`spam`) status.

On your usage - why not just create custom post type for procedures? Comments are much less flexible than posts and kinda single-purposed in nature.

Comment: I found you can set `comment_karma` through *wp_insert_comment()* - so that's good for me. I thought about a custom post type, but the structure of comments (threaded, built-in capabilities, and automatically tied to a post) was so close to what I needed, I hoped not to have to reinvent that wheel.

Answer (score 0):

**comment_karma** can be used like Stack Exchange votes but I did not see any plugin utilises it before.