# What is comment_karma?

Tags: comments

While doing a `var_dump` on the `$comment` object, I see there is a `comment_karma` property. What is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the additional fields in wp\_comments used for?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6475/what-are-the-additional-fields-in-wp-comments-used-for)

Comment: Try googling it?

Comment: googled with no success

Comment: Googled it. Here I am now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the comment_karma property because there is such a column in the comments table. It is meaningless and AFAIK was never used for anything except for maybe some random spam prevention plugin. It is there just for backward compatibility and because no one thinks that removing it will improve anything in a measurable way.

You can use that field if needed, but it is probably a better idea to use your own meta field.